# Kendo Grid Core - Loop through switches in grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm having trouble accessing switches in a grid column.  I want to loop through them and toggle them on after clicking a toolbar button.

The click event is working.  But getting 'undefined' on 'switchInstance ':

Grid Columns:

```
.Columns(columns =>
   {
   columns.Bound(p => p.Exempt).Width(100).Filterable(ftb => 
   ftb.Multi(true)).Sortable(false).ClientTemplate(
        "<input class='exemptSwitch' id='exemptSwitch' \\#if (Exempt) { \\# checked='checked' \\# } \\# 
        type='checkbox' />");
   })
```

Toolbar button:

```
.ToolBar(toolBar =>
 {
      toolBar.Custom()
       .Name("EnableAllFiltered")
       .Text("Enable All Filtered")
       .IconClass("k-icon k-i-play")
       ;
 })
```

Click event:

```
$(function () {
    $(".k-grid-ExemptAllFiltered", "#SubscriberGrid").on("click", function (e) {   //click of custom grid header toolbar button

         $("#SubscriberGrid .exemptSwitch").each(function () {
               var switchInstance = $(this).data("kendoSwitch");
               switchInstance.check(true);
         });
});
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Jon

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this anonymous function is not called in a Kendo Grid event.

Try something like this to see what your `this` is in the Console:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".k-grid-ExemptAllFiltered", "#SubscriberGrid").on("click", function (e) {   //click of custom grid header toolbar button

         $("#SubscriberGrid .exemptSwitch").each(function () {
               console.log(this);
               // var switchInstance = $(this).data("kendoSwitch");
               // switchInstance.check(true);
         });
});
```

If you know that you are always wanting the data from the Kendo Grid, try something like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".k-grid-ExemptAllFiltered", "#SubscriberGrid").on("click", function (e) {   //click of custom grid header toolbar button

         $("#SubscriberGrid .exemptSwitch").each(function () {
               var grid = $('#SubscriberGrid').data('kendoGrid');
               console.log(grid);
               var switchInstance = grid.data("kendoSwitch");
               switchInstance.check(true);
         });
});
```

I do not know the structure of your program, so that might not be right.

Another alternative would be to provide the event item `e`, like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".k-grid-ExemptAllFiltered", "#SubscriberGrid").on("click", function (e) {   //click of custom grid header toolbar button

         $("#SubscriberGrid .exemptSwitch").each(function (e) { // notice the 'e'
               var grid = e.sender;
               console.log(grid);
               var switchInstance = grid.data("kendoSwitch");
               switchInstance.check(true);
         });
});
```

I don't know if any of this helps. I am new to Kendo Grid also, and I am just providing some of the techniques that I have been seeing.

Let me know if it helps.